# Mipmapped texture update freeze

Tags: c++, opengl

I have stumbled upon the following bug.I have a setup where on each frame I update a pretty big texture (1280x720).Right after update I regenerate mipmaps.In the code it looks something like that:

```
        glBindTexture(_target , _id);

    glTexSubImage2D(_target,0,0,0,_imageInfo.width ,_imageInfo.height ,_imageInfo.frmt,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,bytes);

    glGenerateMipmap(_target);

    glBindTexture(_target,0);
```

What I see is that sometimes the update fails and the previous texture is not replaced.May it something to do with mipmap generation process?Is it asynchronous?I mean is it possible that the driver has no sufficient time to update the texture till it goes to shader sampler? 
I use OpenGL 4.2 with NVidia QUADRO K4000 GPU

Comment: Please elaborate ; for instance :What does `glGetError` say to you ? No error ? Did you try to inspect/debug your GL states using `apitrace` or `glIntercept` ?

Comment: AFAIK `glTexSubImage2D` won't resize/allocate the texture storage. Is this done elsewhere? Also `_imageInfo.frmt` needs to be the *in-format* for `bytes`. Have you tried a driver update recently?

Comment: There is absolutely no issues with the API usage.No errors are thrown when debugging.(I use real time debug extension of the API)Also it happens only in release build sporadically.I wasn't able to reproduce it  in debug version or via dev environment.